# why is my express API not responding?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, router

### Background

I am testing a simple Hello World app using NodeJs v7 and express in cloud9.
I am trying to make my example work but I am failing.

### Problem

All my cloud9 configurations are fine so that is not the problem. The problem is my app. When i debug, the route "api/v1/HolaBananas" never gets called and I don't know why!

Even worst, when i make the request, the browser just hangs, like it is waiting for an answer from the server that will never come!

### Code

The `index.js` has the initialization and launch code. It is important for me that I keep this separate from `api.js` for modular reasons.

**index.js**

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.use("/api/v1", require("./api.js"));

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
console.log(`Server listening on port ${process.env.PORT}!`);
```

The `api.js` simply contains the routes and what they are supposed to do.

**api.js**

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");

module.exports = function() {

    const api = express.Router();       

    api.get("/HolaBananas", function(req, res){
        res.send("hello bananas!");
    });

    return api;
};
```

### Question

I am sure I am not using `api.get` in the right way, but I truly want to separate my initialization and launch code from the api.

- How can I fix my code so it works?

### Note

I am following the course

https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-mongodb-using-mean-stack-mongodbx-m101x-0

Comment: have you tried to keep you api code in one file and export that module so that in your main file you just nee to add that module

Comment: refer this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51614/exporting-routes-in-node-js-express-4

Comment: Why don't you initialize the project with [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)? It will create a nice directory structure for you. Additionally, you will by default get a folder for routes. Define your api in any of those routes and you are good to go.

Comment: try to pass express instance into api.js instead of requiring it again. Just shooting in the dark at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

While Vikash Sharma's solution would work, I figured it out by following the recommendation of  Jayant Patil and to read this other question:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51614/exporting-routes-in-node-js-express-4

Turns out we had the same issue, but the given answer to that question also allows me to encapsulate the api file completely inside a function, preserving its scope.

Still, kudos++ for trying!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by two following  ways

```
var api = require("./api.js")();
app.use("/api/v1", require("./api.js"));
```

as API.js return a function reference. so you need to call that function to access route.

Or You need to modify your api.js as follows if you don't want to change  index.js

```
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const api = express.Router();       

    api.get("/HolaBananas", function(req, res){
        res.send("hello bananas!");
    });
module.exports = api;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one subtle thing about it: You have to invoke the function that you export in your `api.js` and use the router object that is returned from that function, so here is what you should do:

You have to replace this line:

```
app.use("/api/v1", require("./api.js"));
```

with this:

```
app.use("/api/v1", require("./api.js")());
```